# How to get nth max correlation coefficient and its index by using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I compute correlation coefficient like this (its just example):

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 7, 9],
     [8, 7, 5]])

corr = np.corrcoef(a)
```

The result is a correlation matrix.

The question is how to get 1st, 2nd (or nth) largest coefficient?

And its index? like `[0,1]` and `[2,1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have a NumPy array and you computed the correlation coefficient like this:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 7, 9],
     [8, 7, 5]])

corr = np.corrcoef(a)
```

Now flatten the array, take the unique coefficients and sort the flattened array:

```py
flat=corr.flatten()
flat = np.unique(flat)
```

The flat array looks like this:

```py
>> array([-0.98198051, -0.95382097,  0.99339927,  1. ])
```

Now to pick `nth largest` element, just pick the right index:

```py
largest = flat[-1]
second_largest = flat[-2]

print(largest)
print(second_largest)
```

```
>> 1.0
>> 0.9933992677987828
```

To find the indices of the corresponding coefficient:

```py
result = np.where(corr == largest)
indices = np.array(result)
print(indices)
```

This prints out the following array. So the indices where the largest coefficient occurs are (0,0), (1,1) and (2,2).

```py
>> array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```